# Strings Failing to Concatinate

Tags: java

I'm trying to print out a final time for a race into a string, so I have my race object with a string property called fastestTime, in the format of Minutes:Seconds.Milliseconds (i.e. "1:15.36").

In my Race class:

```
 public String getFastestTime() {
    if(fastestTime != null)
       return fastestTime;
    else
       return "Unknown";
}
```

In my main:

```
System.out.println("The fastest time was " + race.getFastestTime() + " by " + race.getWinner());
```

For some reason, the only part being printed out is everything after "by". The whole first part is being removed from the print, and I'm really not sure why.

If I only do:

```
System.out.println("The fastest time was " + race.getFastestTime());
```

It prints out fine.

Anyone have any ideas?

UPDATE:

Got it fixed! It looks like I had to trim the string after, thank you all for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: "The fastest time was " is not being printed?

Comment: Correct, only what comes after where the time should be is there.

Comment: What characters are in the String being returned by `race.getFastestTime()`? Any chance that it contains an ANSI escape sequence?

Comment: How `fastestTime` is computed?

Comment: It's possible `race.getWinner()` is returning a return character `\r` as part of its String and therefore overwriting everything prior.

Comment: Got it fixed! It looks like I had to trim the string after, thank you all for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Even though you've resolved the issue, I strongly suggest that you take a look at your implementations of the two methods `race.getFastestTime()` and `race.getWinner()`. I'd put a `trim()` call where they are returned for readability and maintainability. You don't want to run into this same issue again some time down the track.

Answer (score 6):

Seems like `race.getWinner()` is returning a return character `\r` as part of its String and therefore overwriting everything prior.

Try sanitising `race.getWinner()` before printing using something like:

```
race.getWinner().replaceAll("\\r","");
```

or:

```
race.getWinner().trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably there is a carriage return (`\r`) at the end of `fastestTime`. Do `fastestTime.trim()`.